# Help! Getting Error ' Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')' How do I make a Contract Transaction using EtherJS v6

Tags: etherjs

I tried making request to the contract using 'contract.otherFunction()' and they are working fine but just the 'placeBid' function where I have to use add value is giving the error 'Getting Error ' Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')'

All other functionality about connecting the wallet , contract is done already in other components.

Here is the Solidity Code:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

contract AuctionStore {
    address public owner;
    
    struct Product {
        uint256 productId;
        string name;
        string description;
        uint256 auctionEndTime;
        uint256 highestBid;
        address highestBidder;
    }
    
    Product[] public products;

    constructor() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "Only the owner can call this function");
        _;
    }

    modifier productExists(uint256 productId) {
        require(productId < products.length, "Product does not exist");
        _;
    }

    modifier auctionEnded(uint256 productId) {
        require(block.timestamp >= products[productId].auctionEndTime, "Auction has not ended yet");
        _;
    }

    event NewBid(uint256 indexed productId, address indexed bidder, uint256 amount);
    event AuctionEnded(uint256 indexed productId, address winner, uint256 amount);

    function createProduct(string memory _name, string memory _description, uint256 _durationMinutes) public onlyOwner {
        Product memory newProduct = Product({
            productId: products.length,
            name: _name,
            description: _description,
            auctionEndTime: block.timestamp + (_durationMinutes * 1 minutes),
            highestBid: 0,
            highestBidder: address(0)
        });
        products.push(newProduct);
    }

    function placeBid(uint256 productId) public payable productExists(productId) {
        require(block.timestamp < products[productId].auctionEndTime, "Auction has ended");
        require(msg.value > products[productId].highestBid, "Bid must be higher than the current highest bid");

        if (products[productId].highestBidder != address(0)) {
            // Refund the previous highest bidder
            payable(products[productId].highestBidder).transfer(products[productId].highestBid);
        }

        products[productId].highestBidder = msg.sender;
        products[productId].highestBid = msg.value;
        emit NewBid(productId, msg.sender, msg.value);
    }

    function endAuction(uint256 productId) public onlyOwner productExists(productId) auctionEnded(productId) {
        require(products[productId].highestBidder != address(0), "No valid bids");
        payable(owner).transfer(products[productId].highestBid);
        emit AuctionEnded(productId, products[productId].highestBidder, products[productId].highestBid);
    }

    // Fallback function to receive ETH
    receive() external payable {
        revert("Fallback function is disabled. Use placeBid.");
    }

    // Withdraw any remaining funds in the contract
    function withdraw() public onlyOwner {
        uint256 contractBalance = address(this).balance;
        require(contractBalance > 0, "No balance to withdraw");
        payable(owner).transfer(contractBalance);
    }
    
    // Get the number of products listed
    function getNumberOfProducts() public view returns (uint256) {
        return products.length;
    }

    function listAllProducts() public view returns (Product[] memory) {
        return products;
    }
}
```

Here is the ReactJs code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./ProductComp.css";
const { ethers } = require("ethers");

const ProductComp = ({
  productId,
  name,
  description,
  auctionEndTime,
  highestBid,
  highestBidder,
  state,
}) => {
  const { contract } = state;
  const [bidAmount, setBidAmount] = useState("");

  const makeBid = async () => {
    try {
      const tx = await contract.placeBid(productId, { value: 2 });
      let receipt = await tx.wait();
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
  return (
    <div className="prod-comp">
      <h4>{name}</h4>
      <h4>{description}</h4>
      <h4>Current Highest Bid : {highestBid.toString()} ETH</h4>
      <h4>Auction End Time : {auctionEndTime.toString()}</h4>
      <h4>Highest Bidder : {highestBidder}</h4>
      <input
        type="number"
        placeholder="Enter bid amount (in Ether)"
        value={bidAmount}
        onChange={(e) => setBidAmount(e.target.value)}
      />
      <button onClick={makeBid}>Place Bid</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProductComp;
```

Comment: There's no .then() in the JS snippet you provided, the error most likely comes from another bit of code

Answer (score 0):

pls mention down the all packages and take a screenshot of your errors.

etherv6.0 is buggy as compare to ethers5.7.2

Edit: Here is the package.json

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "ethers": "^6.7.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```